# Error creating bean with name 'postsController' defined in file Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I got error, when I run my spring boot application.

my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>blog</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

my PostsController class:

```
package com.project.blog.controllers;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.project.blog.entities.Posts;
import com.project.blog.requests.PostCreateRequest;
import com.project.blog.services.PostsService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/post")
public class PostsController {

    private PostsService postsService;
     
    
    @Autowired
    public PostsController(PostsService postsService) {
        this.postsService = postsService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Posts savePost(@RequestBody PostCreateRequest postReq) {
        return postsService.createOnePost(postReq);
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<Posts> getAllPosts(){
        return postsService.getAllPosts();
    }
}
```

My Posts entity:

```
package com.project.blog.entities;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@Data
public class Posts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;
    
    String title;
    
    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    String post;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    User user;
}
```

my PostRepository :

```
  package com.project.blog.repositories;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.project.blog.entities.Posts;

public interface PostsRepository extends JpaRepository<Posts, Long> {

}
```

my PostService:

```
package com.project.blog.services;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.project.blog.entities.Posts;
import com.project.blog.entities.User;
import com.project.blog.repositories.PostsRepository;
import com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.project.blog.requests.PostCreateRequest;

@Service
public class PostsService {
    private PostsRepository postsRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PostsService(PostsRepository postsRepository,UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.postsRepository = postsRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    } 
    
    public List<Posts> getAllPosts(){
        return postsRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    public Posts createOnePost(PostCreateRequest postReq) {
        
        User user = userRepository.findById(postReq.getUserid()).orElse(null);
        
        if(user == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Posts post = new Posts();
        post.setPost(postReq.getPost());
        post.setTitle(postReq.getTitle());
        post.setUser(user);
        return postsRepository.save(post);
    }
    
    public void deletePostById(Long id) {
        postsRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

And my error message on console :

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postsController' defined in file [/Users/erdemoden/Desktop/Spring-Boot/blog/target/classes/com/project/blog/controllers/PostsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postsService' defined in file [/Users/erdemoden/Desktop/Spring-Boot/blog/target/classes/com/project/blog/services/PostsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
    2022-05-31 00:26:29.796  INFO 2480 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2022-05-31 00:26:29.799  INFO 2480 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2022-05-31 00:26:29.808  INFO 2480 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    2022-05-31 00:26:29.810  INFO 2480 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2022-05-31 00:26:29.821  INFO 2480 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2022-05-31 00:26:29.841 ERROR 2480 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postsController' defined in file [/Users/erdemoden/Desktop/Spring-Boot/blog/target/classes/com/project/blog/controllers/PostsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postsService' defined in file [/Users/erdemoden/Desktop/Spring-Boot/blog/target/classes/com/project/blog/services/PostsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at com.project.blog.BlogApplication.main(BlogApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postsService' defined in file [/Users/erdemoden/Desktop/Spring-Boot/blog/target/classes/com/project/blog/services/PostsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:364) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 49 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        ... 71 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Also I have user and likes entity controller service and jpa repository. What am I doing wrong can you help me. I am new about spring boot.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error logged is: "com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!". You need to scroll to the end of it if you didn't see. It's a problem with `UserRepository`, which I don't think you've provided in the question. The rest of the code you've provided is probably not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the exception again

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.project.blog.entities.User 
com.project.blog.repositories.UserRepository.findbyUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyUserName' found for type 'User'!
```

You are trying to use a spring data query which does not exist or is invalid
the error is in `UserRepository`

```
Optional<User> findByUserName(String name);

or 

Optional<User> findBy<FieldNameInCamelCase>(String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with annotating your repos with the @Repository tag.

And looking at your error message, it looks like its having difficulty with the UserRepository specifically, you might want to start looking there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing findbyUserName with findByUsername and now it works